# Javascript - add text to form field that can be added to but not deleted

Tags: javascript, forms

I want some text to dynamically be added to a field that the user can then write more in but not remove the pre filled in text. I have got this:

```
var foo = document.title;
var msgField = document.getElementById('message');
msgField.value = "I am interested in " + foo + " ";
```

I want the "i am interested in Title " to be already filled in on the form but not able to be deleted by the user. I DO want the user to be able to write more information after this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: this message should be in label or in text-box?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function addText(elId,text) {
    text += document.getElementById(elId).value ;
}
```

or:

```
function addText(elId,text) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elId);
    var txt = document.createTextNode(text);
    txt.appendChild(obj);
}
```

Hope this can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to enforce in a few ways, but it *will* be clunky and ugly.

Try to style it to appear as part of the textbox, instead.  For example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid brown; font: 14px monospace; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 10px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="interestedInHeader" style="width: 100%;">I am interested in</div>
  <textarea id="interestedInText" style="width: 100%; font: 14px monospace; bottom: 0; top: 18px; border: none; position: absolute;">bunnies and ponies</textarea>
</div>​

document.getElementById("interestedInHeader").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("interestedInText").focus();
}
```

​

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8xjf/

Answer (score -1):

The question is not clear to me. Are you looking for this kind of code?

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="fnc()"/>
<input type="text" id="message" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
var foo = "MYSITE";
msgField=document.getElementById("message");
msgField.value = "I am interested in " + foo + " ";

}
</script>
```

Comment: How does that prevent editing the "I am interested in" prefix?

Comment: The message is static. It'll be dynamic if you pick the message from a text box or some input. There is nothing mentioned in the question. So I felt it unnecessary. Tell me if someone needs it

Comment: The question says "not able to be deleted by the user". What are you doing differently from the code in the question?